# File get contents params

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm making a PHP crawler to explore e-shop called alza.cz. I want links to all products in that e-shop. I'm on address: http://www.alza.cz/notebooky/18842920.htm., but this display only first 21 items. To get all items I must go to address: http://www.alza.cz/notebooky/18842920.htm#f&pg=1/10000.

Crawler uses `file_get_contents` to get HTML of the page, which is then parsed using DOM. Problem is, that it looks like that `file_get_contents` ignores that part after # (returns only first 21 items instead of all). Any ideas?

Comment: Both the links return `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied` error for me.

Comment: both links give 403 error

Comment: Seems okay here. The problem when scraping this site is that regardless of the way you get the next set of items (either the "21 dalších..." or the regular paginator), it uses an AJAX request and not a regular page access. Thus, you need to explore via AJAX - have you got a live AJAX viewer (in your browser) you can use to determine how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_get_contents would ignore the `#xxxxx` part of the URL (the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)), and would not include it in the requested URL. It's something a user agent would use on the client side - most likely, the website has some Javascript which would use AJAX to load a new page of results.

You could see if the page obeys the [Google AJAX Crawling Specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/), though based on your example, it doesn't look like it. If you see "hash bang" fragment identifiers like `#!foo=bar`, that's a good sign.

So, you'll need to observe the AJAX requests in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [similar](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) and replicate the same requests yourself.